# what the purpose of declaring a variable with "const constant"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal, metalkit

In Metal shader, What is the purpose of declaring a variable like `const constant Vertex *vertexArray [[buffer(0)]]` (with `const constant` I mean)? why constant alone is not enough? also, what is the difference between `constant` and `const` ?

Also in the same way what is the difference between `const device` and `constant` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`const` is a *type qualifier*. `constant` and `device` are *address spaces*.

`const` prevents you from modifying the thing to which it applies:

```
int a = 15;
a = 16; // Fine; reassigning to a non-const variable

const int b = 15;
b = a; // Error: attempt to write to a read-only constant

int d = 18;
int const* c = &a;
*c = 17; // Error: attempt to write value through a pointer to const int
c = &d;  // Fine; reassigning (a different address) to a (non-const) pointer

int *const e = &d;
*e = a; // Fine; assigning to pointee through pointer to non-const int
e = c;  // Error: attempt to reassign const pointer
```

Hopefully these examples adequately illustrate the semantics of variables and constants, and how the rules work in the case of pointers.

In Metal, pointers always reside in a particular address space. If you take the address of a variable with automatic storage in a Metal shader function (i.e. a "local" variable), that pointer is in the *thread* address space. Buffer parameters, on the other hand, are always in the *constant* or *device* address space.

`device` buffers are used to hold memory whose elements will be accessed roughly once, as you might do when fetching vertex data sequentially in a vertex function. On the other hand, `constant` buffers hold data that might be accessed by many invocations of a function, as with uniform data.

You cannot write to a buffer in the `constant` address space. Here's the most important sentence in this answer: **All pointers in the `constant` address space are implicitly const-qualified.**

You can form new pointers in the constant address space, and by the rules explained above, you can reassign them. But attempting to write to their pointee will produce a compiler error.

Suppose you write a fragment function with the following parameter:

```
constant Light *lights [[buffer(0)]]
```

Then in the function body you could say this:

```
constant Light *light = &lights[0];
```

And this:

```
light = &lights[1];
```

But not this:

```
light->color = float4(1, 1, 1, 1); // Error: attempt to write to variable with const-qualified type "const constant Light *"
```

Again, note that in this last example, even though we didn't say that the constant pointer should be a pointer-to-const, it is. For this reason, further qualifying a `constant` pointer with `const` (before the asterisk) is redundant.

Now let's talk a bit about `device` pointers.

In contrast to `constant` buffers, which are always read-only, it is possible in many contexts to write to `device` buffers. However, you often treat device buffers as read-only (e.g., in most vertex functions). To indicate this intent to the compiler, you can add `const` to a device buffer pointer parameter. This will prevent you from inadvertently writing to a buffer you are only intending to read. Recent versions of the Metal shader compiler emit a warning if you take a `device` pointer to non-const type in an inappropriate context, which is why it's generally a good idea to get in the habit of writing `const device` for such parameters.

But writing `const constant` is redundant and never necessary.