# Address spaces in Metal: constant vs const device

Tags: ios, gpu, gpgpu, metal

For the longest time I was thinking that whenever the buffer is writeable we need to declare it as `device`, if read-only then `constant`. But now I realized that in many code samples on the internet including the official resources it is  often not that simple. It's obvious that `device` would work everywhere where `constant` works, but in many cases I see that people use `device` on read-only buffers seemingly intentionally even going as far as declaring one buffer as `const device` but using `constant` on another buffers in the same kernel like so:

```
kernel void test
(
 constant float4 *buffer0 [[buffer(0)]],
 const device float4 *buffer1 [[buffer(1)]],
 device float4 *out_buffer [[buffer(2)]],
 )
{
    // both buffer0 and buffer1 are read-only, why they possibly would need different address spaces???
}
```

The documentation is not clear enough for my understanding.

So the question is - in which cases it is better to use `device`/`const device` instead of `constant` address space on read-only buffers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what the purpose of declaring a variable with "const constant"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010429/what-the-purpose-of-declaring-a-variable-with-const-constant)

Comment: @HamidYusifli no, it only says that "you often treat device buffers as read-only (e.g., in most vertex functions)", but never explains why you do that. I don't remember if vertex functions specifically require the use of device buffers in read-only situations, but in my question I'm asking about the situations where you're free to choose device vs constant on your own, like in the case of kernel functions.